# foreman UI puppet run fails

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have foreman proxy running on port 8000.

foreman running on port 3000

puppetmaster service running on port 8140.

Also, I have 3 puppet agent configured,

1. localhost puppet agent
2. remote host agent 1
3. remote host agent 2

When I execute puppet run from foreman GUI, localhost works fine, I am able to make puppet run on my master host. Because I added foreman-proxy in /etc/sudoers file and everything working fine.

But after making configuration changes for puppet classes for those two remote hosts, I tried to run puppet run from foreman GUI, but ended with the below errors.

I think it's unable to connect to the remote hosts...what do you think ?

> Error: failed to execute puppetrun: ERF12-4252
>   [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to execute Puppet run
>   ([RestClient::RequestTimeout]: Request Timeout) for proxy
>   http://domain.com:8000/puppet

**UPDATE 1:**
I followed this article and opened port **8139** as mentioned and added **listen=true** in **/etc/puppet/puppet.conf**.
Now I am getting this error

> Error: failed to execute puppetrun: ERF12-4252
>   [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to execute Puppet run
>   ([RestClient::InternalServerError]: 500 Internal Server Error) for
>   proxy http://lhdgameslab.com:8000/puppet

**contents from /var/log/foreman-proxy/proxy.log**

```
E, [2016-09-27T10:53:41.585056 #17092] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
E, [2016-09-27T10:54:33.020211 #17092] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
E, [2016-09-27T10:58:50.908303 #17092] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
E, [2016-09-27T11:02:37.603161 #17092] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
E, [2016-09-27T11:29:27.946510 #23644] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
E, [2016-09-27T11:29:36.748147 #23644] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
```

Server Puppet Version: 3.0.1

Agent Puppet Version : 2.7.11

**UPDATE 2:**

```
   [2016-09-27T12:05:35.403274 #26943] DEBUG -- : close: xxx.xxx.xx.xx:39355
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:44.330022 #26943] DEBUG -- : accept: xxx.xxx.xx.xx:39386
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:44.331547 #26943] DEBUG -- : Rack::Handler::WEBrick is invoked.
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:44.336316 #26943] DEBUG -- : verifying remote client xxx.xxx.xx.xx against trusted_hosts ["xxx.com"]
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:44.337116 #26943] DEBUG -- : require_ssl_client_verification: skipping, non-HTTPS request
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:44.338831 #26943] DEBUG -- : about to execute: ["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/sbin/puppetrun", "--host", "yyyy.com"]
W, [2016-09-27T12:05:45.270639 #26943]  WARN -- : Non-null exit code when executing '["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/sbin/puppetrun", "--host", "yyyy.com"]'
E, [2016-09-27T12:05:45.271021 #26943] ERROR -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
D, [2016-09-27T12:05:45.271080 #26943] DEBUG -- : Failed puppet run: Check Log files
I, [2016-09-27T12:05:45.271835 #26943]  INFO -- : xxx.xxx.xx.xx - - [27/Sep/2016 12:05:45] "POST /puppet/run HTTP/1.1" 500 34 0.9376
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/805395/puppet-run-giving-error-failed-to-execute-puppetrun-erf12-4252

Comment: m0dlx, thats 404 not found, but what I am facing is totally different

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Please provide logs from foreman-proxy, preferably with log_level set to DEBUG.

Comment: It'd also be very useful to know precisely which versions of Foreman and Puppet are installed on both the server and agent.

Comment: updated my question, Please check.... but puppet version mismatch is there... will that create any problem ???? but its running fine when I issue the same command directly in agent

Comment: The logs look to be at ERROR level, please include DEBUG logs (/etc/foreman-proxy/settings.yml).

Comment: m0dlx, see update 2, got the logs for you..... /usr/sbin/puppetrun doesn't exist in remote host :(:(:(

Comment: Check you have the sudo rules in place, and attempt sudoing to foreman-proxy, and _then_ run the command it's attempting: `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/puppetrun --host yyyy.com` - check for any error.

Comment: m0dlx, I found the answer, creating auth.conf in /etc/puppet/ solved that issue

Comment: m0dlx, if you don't mind, give +1 for this question :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating auth.conf in /etc/puppet location solved the issue....

**/etc/puppet/auth.conf**

```
path /run
method save
auth any
allow *
```

Comment: m0dlx, even after restarting puppet agent after making this change, I need ed to execute puppet run button multiple times... on 4th or 5th attempt, its started working... will it take some time to propagate  the changes ???